# CSS3 классы, пространство имён

Tags: html5, css3

Возвращаясь к Веб-дизайну после перерыва, скачал шаблон. И обнаружил непонятное.

```
.\33 u, .\33 u\24 {...}
.row.\31 50\25 > * {...}
```

Примерно так. Что за символ \ в названии класса, и что означает 50\25 u\24?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#cssescapes

Comment: Так экранируются недопустимые символы. Почитайте пункт 7 https://habrahabr.ru/post/262783/

Comment: Похожий вопрос (англ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882839/what-does-container-31-25-25-mean-in-css